# Is there any way to make prompts not require a case sensitive answer ?

Tags: javascript, prompt, url-parameters

I am having a URL parameter like this .

**/?name=John&accountID=123456789&email=jdoe@tc.com**

When the page reloads a prompt box appears so that user can enter parameters inorder to get their value. Eg: IF a user enters **name** and click on OK then **John** will come as alert, or if user enters **accountID** then **123456789** will come as alert. This is working for me .

```
  if ( atts[0] !== '' ) {
    param = prompt( 'Enter desired URL parameter:' );

    for ( i = 0; i < atts.length; i++ ) {
        pair = atts[ i ].split( '=' );

        if ( pair[0] === param ) {
            alert( pair[1] );
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But the problem is when user types **NAME** (full caps) its not working . How to make this case insensitive. Mean **NAME** should be = **name**, or **AcCOUntId** should be = **accountID** . How to get this without using **hard coded** values (like name, email or accountID), URL can be anything . I need to match the values or strings which user enters.

Comment: JavaScript strings have `toLowerCase()` and `toUpperCase()` conversion methods.

Comment: @Pointy yes but what if url is in camelCase ? or even like this AcCOUntId . ?

Comment: The URL is case insensitive, your problem lies in JavaScript. I‘ll show you a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the comparison to following could help you:

```
if ( pair[0].toLowerCase() === param.toLowerCase() ) {
    alert( pair[1] );
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm . Thanks alot .

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare two strings case insensitive, you can lower or upper both strings like this:

```
if ( atts[0] !== '' ) {
    param = prompt( 'Enter desired URL parameter:' );

    for ( i = 0; i < atts.length; i++ ) {
        pair = atts[ i ].split( '=' );

        if ( pair[0].toLowerCase() === param.toLowerCase() ) {
            alert( pair[1] );
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

See MDN for [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)